# How to control playback state function on MPMusicPlayer

Tags: iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller

how to control playback state function in MPMusicPlayer....for example i want open

ipod playlist file  when the no item available at the end of next track...

how it is possible on iphone.....please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of my code that does that:

```
    MPMediaQuery *everything = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];

[everything setGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingPlaylist];

self.playlists = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[everything collections]];
```

....

```
    NSArray *songsList = [[self.playlists objectAtIndex: currentPlayListIndex] items];

int nowIndex = [songsList indexOfObject:nowPlayingViewController.nowPlayingItem];

if(++nowIndex >= [songsList count]) 
    nowIndex = 0;

if(![self playItem: [songsList objectAtIndex:nowIndex]])
```